# React-native-navigation navigate through a different component instead of from a page

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

My home page contains a View. This view contains a flat list with items. The flat list is being rendered through a different component

I should be able to use something like *this.props.navigation.navigate('DetailPage')* from the  component not from my homePage.

I think i should pass the navigation as a prop to the  but not sure how i could do that.

**Navigation File**

```
export const HomePageStack = StackNavigator({
      Homepage:{
          screen:homePage,
      },
      DetailPage:{
          screen: DetailPage,
      }

})
```

**Home Page Screen**

```
render(){
   return(
       <View>
           <DetailedArea />
       </View>
)}
```

**Detailed Area**

```
render(){
   return(
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.navigation.navigate('DetailPage')}>
         <Text>CLICK HERE TO GO TO DETAIL PAGE</TEXT>
      </TouchableHighlight>
)}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `HomeScreen` has `this.props.navigation`, but it isn't passed down to `DetailedArea`.

I recommend the following:

**HomeScreen**

```
render(){
   return(
       <View>
           <DetailedArea onNavigate={() =>  this.props.navigation.navigate('DetalPage')} />
       </View>
)}
```

**DetailedArea**

```
render(){
   return(
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.onNavigate}>
         <Text>CLICK HERE TO GO TO DETAIL PAGE</TEXT>
      </TouchableHighlight>
)}
```